# Can't update data in Sqlite3 php

Tags: php, sqlite, sql-update

I'm trying  to make simple api using php .
everything goes smoothly except  updating .
here is my code code for index (route):

```
$router->post('/api/update/{id}', function ($id) use ($product) {
 //   $_POST['id'] = $id;
    echo $product->update($_POST);
    //var_dump($_POST);
});
```

and here is my code update method in products class :

```
public function update(array $data) {
        /** @var TYPE_NAME $id */
        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE products SET name= ?, price= ? ,amount= ? WHERE id= ?");
        $query->execute(array($data['name'], $data['price'], $data['amount'],$data['id']));
        return json_encode(["msg" => "The Product was updated successfully."]);
        //return json_encode($data);
    }
```

when I make post request  I get this error :

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "name" in **/storage/emulated/0/www/products_manager/app/Products.php** on line **52**

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "price" in **/storage/emulated/0/www/products_manager/app/Products.php** on line **52**

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "amount" in **/storage/emulated/0/www/products_manager/app/Products.php** on line **52**

**Warning**:  Undefined array key "id" in **/storage/emulated/0/www/products_manager/app/Products.php** on line **52**
{"msg":"The Product was updated successfully."}

I try to update  product  data in my SQLITE3 databases.

Comment: that means there is no  `name` key in array `$data` .the `$_POST` you are passing to update method, not contains `name` , `price` ,
`amount` ,..

Comment: when I var_dump the ``$data`` array it print the values correctly.

Comment: you need to validate the form before updating .

Comment: I have validated that the ``$_POST`` is not empty  and contains all required data. but still get the same error